# List<> property able to have different types that all inherit from the same class

Tags: c#, .net

So I have for example this class

```
    public abstract class Feature
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I will have different classes that all inherit this but are in other ways different

so for one example I will have this one

```
public class FirstClass: Feature
{
    public string FirstClassKey { get; set; }
}
```

And then i have another class that will have a `List<>` that I want to have the `FirstClassKey` and all Feature properties in it but it needs to be generic since if I have a similar `SecondClass` that also will inherit `Feature` class I want to be able to use the below class for a List that will have `SecondClassKey` and then all of Feature properties.

```
public class FeatureCollection
{
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public List<> Features { get;set; }
}
```

So sometimes a `FeatureCollection` object will look like

```
{
 Type: "SomeType",
 Features = [FirstClassKey: "12", Id: "20", Type: "FeatureType"]
}
```

And sometimes like

```
{
 Type: "SomeType",
 Features = [SecondClassKey: "48", Id: "20", Type: "FeatureType"]
}
```

Is this possible or will i have to create a `FeatureCollection` class for each of the different classes that will inherit the `Feature` abstract class

Comment: `List<>` is illegal as a type declaration.  Did you mean to use `List<Feature>`?

Comment: Or are you asking how you can pass an arbitrary type? That would require `FeatureCollection` to take a generic parameter (i.e. `T`) that you pass to `List` (`List<T>`).

Comment: Does the existence of JSON(ish) data in your question imply you're trying to deserialize data? And if so, does the `Type` property indicate which type of object is in the features collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly what you want to accomplish, but it seems to me you want to make the `FeatureCollection` generic:

```
public class FeatureCollection<TFeature> where TFeature : Feature
{
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public List<TFeature> Features { get; set; }
}
```

Now `FeatureCollection<FirstClass>` can only store instances of `FirstClass` or instances of types that derive from `FirstClass`, while `FeatureCollection<SecondClass>` can't store `FirstClass`, but can store `SecondClass`...